# What are the pros and cons of using larger tiles in a 2d game with freely placed entities?

Tags: 2d, tilemap, tiles, optimization, tilesets

I am working on a 2d game with the Godot Engine and I'm about to start drawing the tiles for the ground tileset. These will be used solely for the purpose of painting the ground because the trees, houses, etc in the map would be loaded into their individual entities and will be place-able anywhere.

My question is should I draw smaller or larger tiles for the ground? What would be the pros and cons of doing so? Memory consumption? Faster loading? Etc

Comment: It sounds like you accurately understand the trade-offs here: large tiles have more pixels, so they're heavier in memory and load times, and take longer for an artist to draw. But they can also be less repetitive than seeing the same small tiles over and over. What [tag:performance-budgeting]/production budgeting have you done to establish how much memory you can set aside for tiles and how many unique sprites you have time to create?

Comment: Good point, I haven't actually done any kind of performance budgeting, I'm moreof just looking to get a bullet point list of the pros and cons of using larger tiles so I can weigh my options. Aside from what I listed (RAM and loadtimes) are there any other pros and cons in the technical side (not the artistic side)